# Some QSoundEffects don't play (ever) on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, audio, qtmultimedia

My game has a couple of different simultaneous `QSoundEffects` (mainly gun sounds) and I play them simply like this:

```
effect.setVolume(0.5f);
effect.play();
```

The sound data has been loaded beforehand when the application initializes.

On my `Ubuntu` desktop this works perfectly, but on `Android` some of the sounds don't play. The problematic sounds can be different each time until I restart the app.

What could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to self:

It seems that there's a maximum count for simultaneous `QSoundEffects`. This was expected, but it seems to work so that only the first N sound effects are playing in the order of their creation. The rest are just ignored. It doesn't help anything if you first stop some other sounds that are playing. This makes me believe that the `QSoundEffects` are permanently mapped to free audio streams.

I tried to set some of the sources on-the-fly when needed, but it was unstable and `PulseAudio` crashed randomly. So...now it seems that I'll take the `OpenAL Soft` route as it's easy to compile for `Android`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?   Six years later, and it's still an issue.  Is there a way to "un-map" sound effects?

Comment: Yes I did...by using OpenAL Soft and forgetting QSoundEffects.